# Plot a sequence of histograms?

Tags: plotting, histograms

How can I plot a sequence of histograms, one after the other, in 3D? Here is an example [image]

Answer (score 10):

When you have lots of data, you should consider using `SmoothKernelDistribution` or `SmoothHistogram` as I'm assuming that you must be thinking that the underlying true distribution is relatively smooth (and does not look like a jagged histogram).

These "nonparametric density estimates" work fine overlapped in 2D and if one really feels the need, one can create a 3D version much like what you've displayed for histograms.

```
(* Generate 4 sets of data *)
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#[[1]], #[[2]]], 200] & /@ 
  {{0, 15}, {10, 12}, {20, 10}, {30, 5}};

(* Find smooth kernel density estimates *)
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[#] & /@ data;

(* Plot resulting densities *)
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{10 (# - 1), x, PDF[skd[[#]], x]}, {x, -30, 50, .1}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4},
  Filling -> Bottom, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Multiple smoothed histograms in 3D]

And the 2D version where the differences among curves is more readily apparent:

```
Plot[{PDF[skd[[1]], x], PDF[skd[[2]], x], PDF[skd[[3]], x], PDF[skd[[4]], x]},
  {x, -30, 50}, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}]
```

[image: Multiple smooth histograms in 2D]

Answer (score 8):

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1/2], 500];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 2], 500];
```

**Histogram3D with a custom ChartElementFunction**

```
cef[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, {zmin_, zmax_}}, ___] := 
 Polygon[{{xmin, ymin, zmin}, {xmax, ymin, zmin}, {xmax, ymin, zmax}, {xmin, ymin, zmax}}]

Histogram3D[MapIndexed[Thread[{#, #2[[1]]}] &, {data1, data2, data3}], 
 {{-6, 6, 0.2}, {1}},
 ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},  BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> False, Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cef]
```

[image]

**Post-process Histogram output to 3D histograms:**

```
ClearAll[rectanglesTo3DPolygons ]
rectanglesTo3DPolygons = Module[{i = 1}, 
    Cases[#, {dir__, rects : {{{_Rectangle}} ..}} :> 
      With[{j = i++}, {dir, Opacity[.7], 
        EdgeForm[{Thin, White}], {rects[[All, 1, 1]] /. 
          Rectangle[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, o___] :> 
           Polygon[{{a, j, b}, {c, j, b}, {c, j, d}, {a, j, d}}]}}], {0, Infinity}]] &;


hist = Histogram[{data1, data2, data3}, {.2},  
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, ImageSize -> 300];

facegrids = {{{1, 0, 0}, {Range[3], {1}}}, {{-1, 0,  0}, {Range[3], {1}}},
  {{0, 0, 1}, {{}, Range[3]}}, {{0,  0, -1}, {{},Range[3]}}};

hist3d = Graphics3D[rectanglesTo3DPolygons@hist, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 4}, All}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
   FaceGrids -> facegrids, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{hist, hist3d}]
```

[image]

```
hist2 = Histogram[{data1, data3}, {.2}, ChartStyle -> {Red,  Blue}, 
  ImageSize -> 300]; 
hist3d2 = Graphics3D[rectanglesTo3DPolygons@hist2, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3}, All}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  FaceGrids -> facegrids, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{hist2, hist3d2}]
```

[image]

**BarChart with a custom ChartElementFunction**

```
heights = HistogramList[#, {-6, 6, .2}][[2]] & /@ {data1, data2, data3};

BarChart3D[heights, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue}, None}, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cef, PlotRangePadding -> {0, 2, 0}]
```

[image]